# Should you index a primary key?

Tags: sql, database, performance, indexing, db2

I am having some issues concerning the gray area between primary keys and indices, and their relationship. I know that in db2 when a primary key is created, a unique index is automatically assigned to that attribute.

Can there be any type of performance implications of assigning a different index to the primary key? If so how and when do these performance improvements occur?

Thanks

Comment: (1) I don't see why you'd want another index assigned to a primary key or why it'd be different.  (2) I am not aware of any performance difference.

Comment: `gray area between primary keys and indices,` There is no grey area. `primary key` is an *abstract* (theoretical/data modelling) concept.  `index` is a *physical* object. (often used or needed or implied by a PK)

Comment: A primary key is a *unique* identifier for its row.  I'm not sure what you mean by a "different index" from the unique index some databases use to create a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own index will give you full control over all possible index option dokumented [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000919.html)

This could be achieved by creating the table without a primary key, creating the index and the altering the table adding the primary key.

One option with performance implications could be the INCLUDE option where you can add additional rows to the unique index which are not considered determining the uniqueness but may be used for index only access.
Ususally it is more important for most people to follow a naming concept by doing it this way.

Comment: Good to hear - so could you mark it as answer then please - thanks